# How to end a file in a newline in c?

Tags: c, file, newline

```
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

hello everyone,

These are the last few lines of my code, is this how you end a file with a newline in C? Or do they mean something else when they say you should always end a file with a newline?

When i tried to put a newline under endif it gave me an error, so i could only put it there or am i not supposed to print the newline? I am supposed to hand it in with a newline according to my school but im not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Are you taking about newlines in a data file your program generates, or the newlines in the source code file you have shown?

Comment: Last time when i handed it in he looked at my code like this and didnt see a newline, they only said that it should end in a newline not how to do it, I looked it up online and there seems to be a general rule that you should do that, but i dont know how to apply it.

Comment: Perhaps you should always end a multiline text file with a newline, but equally you should never assume that a text file you are reading ends with a newline.

Comment: I geuss that could be it? I do know that my TA said that apparently if you don't end a  file with a newline it could brake the program.

Comment: So it is about the [trailing newline in the code file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743). You realize that you have put quite a lot of newlines already in that file? There is one after `printf("\n");`, there is one after `return 0;`, there is one after the `}`. So you should be familiar with putting newlines in there; so do after the `#endif` what you have done to all the other lines to cause there to be a newline.

Comment: Oooh now i get it Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're using tools (like VS Code) made for Windows, aren't you? On Windows, newlines _separate_ lines (so they go between lines, but there's no expectation to have one at the end of the file); but on UNIX, newlines _terminate_ lines (so a line isn't valid unless it has a newline on the end).

Answer (score 2):

That fragment ends with `f` (from `#endif`).  The file should end with an empty line:

```
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

The problem (in theory) is that *any* file can be `#include`'d, so if for example you had a header xx.h ending in `#endif` and say a yy.h starting `#if`, code:

#include "xx.h"
#include "yy.h"

The pre-processor after inclusion would see:

```
#endif#if
```

all on one line and would fail.  There are of course many other syntactical nonsenses that can be generated in this way.  Often you get away with it because most source-files of any kind start with a *boiler-plate* comment which is most often semantically and syntactically benign.  On modern compilers you generally get an diagnostic warning of the malformed source.

In C++ the compiler is required to behave *as if* there was a newline, even if it is not explicit to avoid this problem.  That may be in later C standards too (I have not looked), or a compiler may I guess choose to add it implicitly in any case and issue a warning.

Comment: You don't need an explicit empty line if you're saving the file as a proper UNIX text file (as on UNIX, newlines _terminate_ lines and are required after each and every line rather than _separating_ lines and being required only between them). Only Windows-oriented tools require an extra/blank line to be added to have a terminating newline.

Comment: It avoids far more issues than just this one: for example, a `while read` loop in UNIX shell will ignore any line with no trailing newline. And this is black-letter POSIX specification, not any mere convention: see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403 and https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206

Comment: There absolutely is enforcement. The Open Group are the people who decide if your operating system is certified as UNIX and able to use the trademark.

Comment: You're telling people to make files that git will flag warnings over (as it does with blank lines at the end of files and blank space at the end of lines) as a workaround for misconfigurations that can be avoided in the first place by consistently using correct editor configuration for your target platform (and C preprocessors built for that same platform); this is indefensible, and I would be constantly correcting files committed by coworkers who followed your "advice" (or, rather: I would be adjusting our CI to reject those files so they never made it into a shared branch at all).